# Unable to get typescript typings to match

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am unable to get the following code to work.

I am trying to fetch some data and handling all the falsy/error cases and then passing on the cleaned data to another function. But the typings don't seem to match when I call the second function.

> Type 'Error | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'

```js
interface SomeType {
  a: number[] | null | Error
  b: number[] | null
}

type Omit <T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
type ExcludeUnusableValues<T,K extends keyof T,C = Error | null>
  = Omit<T, K> & {
    [a in K]-? : Exclude<T[a], C>
  }

function fetchData() {
  const obj: SomeType = {
    a: [1, 2, 3],
    b: null
  }
  if (obj.a === null || obj.a instanceof Error) {
    return null
  }

  //  Type 'Error | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'
  useData(obj)
}

function useData(param1: ExcludeUnusableValues < SomeType, 'a' > ) {
  console.log(param1)
}
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20SomeType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20Error%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Omit%20%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%0D%0Atype%20ExcludeUnusableValues%3CT%2CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%2CC%20%3D%20Error%20%7C%20null%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3D%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Ba%20in%20K%5D-%3F%20%3A%20Exclude%3CT%5Ba%5D%2C%20C%3E%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fetchData()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20obj%3A%20SomeType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20null%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20if%20(obj.a%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%7C%7C%20obj.a%20instanceof%20Error)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%20Type%20'Error%20%7C%20number%5B%5D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'number%5B%5D'%0D%0A%20%20useData(obj)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20useData(param1%3A%20ExcludeUnusableValues%20%3C%20SomeType%2C%20'a'%20%3E%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(param1)%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: What's `bar()`?  If you'd like a meaningful answer to your question, please consider editing the code into a [mcve] so that others can see the same issue you're seeing with a minimum of effort.

Comment: Sorry for that, I am trying to pass `obj` into `useData` function. @pushkin, @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around the issue by moving your type checking logic into a type predicate. Here is your example, modified with `isUsableType`:

```
interface SomeType {
  a: number[] | null | Error
  b: number[] | null
}

function isUsableType(obj: SomeType): obj is ExcludeUnusableValues < SomeType, 'a' > {
  return obj.a!==null && !(obj.a instanceof Error)
}

type Omit <T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
type ExcludeUnusableValues<T,K extends keyof T,C = Error | null>
  = Omit<T, K> & {
    [a in K]-? : Exclude<T[a], C>
  }

function fetchData() {
  const obj: SomeType = {
    a: [1, 2, 3],
    b: null
  }

  if (isUsableType(obj)) {
    useData(obj)
  } else return null;

}

function useData(param1: ExcludeUnusableValues < SomeType, 'a' > ) {  
  console.log(param1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. But why is it not able to infer the same thing without a predicate?

Comment: @RevanthM I think that ideally it should, but Typescript is a practical language and lacks mathematical precision.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** Remove type **Error** from **SomeType.a**.
**Long Answer:**

```
a: number[] | null;
```

**a** can be either array of number or null. It is perfectly fine because either **a** exits or it doesn't.

```
a: number[] | null | Error;
```

Here, type **Error** is causing problem because **Error** does not have same property/functions that array of number has. For this to work, all the types must have some similar properties.

**Another solution:**
Typecast the obj to appropiate type:

```
useData(<{a: number[], b: number[]}>obj)
```

Comment: I need the Error instance as well. It will be handled at other levels. My main question though is why would `obj.a` have `Error` when I am calling `useData` function? I have a typeguard before it which handles the `Error` and `return`s if it is found.

Comment: @RevanthM I have added another solution also if you need Error type.  When you calling userData function, the compiler still cannot guarantee the obj.a cannot be null. You have to manually specify it.